Old Neural Network GitHub is not working with current TensorFlow
I would like to use this neural network in my project: https://github.com/HarborZeng/pointnet2-keras/tree/master
I am using Ubuntu 22.4
it was previously used in the project, and I am reviving this project again and trying to upgrade it but I cannot make it work in its original state, the thing is, this project was written some years ago, so the current version of TensorFlow does not support stuff in this repository like backend.set_session() for example.
I have tried multiple solutions like using compat.v1 and so but a function like set_session() is just completely not available no matter what solution I find on the internet.
I was thinking of cloning the repo of an older version of TensorFlow but I am not sure how hard is it to set it up and would it take a long time, or there might be just a work around to that issue?

Instead of trying to get TF v1 to run, maybe just look for a newer implementation in TF v2 or torch? Also, there might be new state-of-the-art models which have a better performance and are implemented in a recent version of a framework.
